Chinese Language temporary logo --- can we vote?
Update: The top candidate has now been implemented.  See Let's change the temporary logo from "Cn" to 漢?

In the post Chinese Language temporary logo the idea of a temporary Chinese.SE logo was raised (see also Logo Design for Chinese Language & Usage Site from 7 years ago).
Other sites have used this to great effect, which can be seen at Area 51; for example: Chess.SE uses a rook ♜, Poker.SE uses a club ♣, and so on.  Currently the logo is "Cn" which, in my opinion, is not "special".
What we need to consider:

it must be a unicode symbol that renders in most browsers,

it needs to distinguish Chinese vs. Japanese (e.g. 文, 中, and 語 are also Japanese),

potential issues with simplified vs. traditional Chinese (choosing traditional seems less controversial: mainland China sometimes uses traditional hanzi for logos),

Chinese.SE allows questions about all Chinese dialects, and includes all aspects of the Chinese language, speaking, writing, etc. (affecting 言),

it should distinguish the Chinese language vs. China itself (affecting 中 and 华/華), and



if you're choosing a logo it should be a good "favicon" in a browser -- HostileFork

This is particularly pertinent for Hot Network Questions, where the logo is very small.  This also affects item 3 (simplified vs. traditional).


I'll list candidates as answers to this post to vote on.  I deliberately present the suggestions in the previous post without any context, as any logo that's implemented will be seen without any context.  Please use the previous post to discuss context.
I only present the candidates from Chinese Language temporary logo which I consider to have a chance at being voted to the top: 夏, 汉, 漢, and 永.  My opinion is that any one of these would be better than "Cn".
Please vote on the following possibilities.  Please ensure you make only one upvote.  We can distinguish upvotes from downvotes, so I'm hoping downvotes can be used to indicate strong disagreement ("hold on, you've missed something important...").

Shall we set some rules? (1) No downvotes, (2) one vote per user? To be honest, I wish a non-Chinese SE user made this poll, because currently you (Becky) cannot vote.

I don't really mind either of these: downvotes can be distinguished from upvotes, and they highlight controversy (if any arises), and upvoting multiple characters indicates someone likes more than one (I don't think it gives any more "voting power").

I think that having multiple votes by one user skews the influence of that user on the outcome, if other people don't do the same.

Alright, let's do one upvote per person.  (It's on a "good faith" basis---we have no way to verify this, although I expect the kinds of users who view meta.Chinese.SE are not out to stir up trouble.)

漢

For maximum compatibility, we might consider using U+FA47 CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-FA47 漢 instead of the standard U+6F22 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-6F22 漢. Otherwise, the top right component of the character will appear incorrectly as 艹 instead of 廿, if the user displays the character with a Japanese font.

永

汉

夏
